# C++ vector problem

Tags: c++

I have the following class declaration:

```
class DEMData
{
private:
    int bitFldPos;
    int bytFldPos;
    const char* byteOrder;
    const char* desS;
    const char* engUnit;
    const char* oTag;
    const char* valType;
    int index;
public:
    DEMData();
    //DEMData(const DEMData &d);
    void SetIndex(int index);
    int GetIndex() const;
    void SetValType(const char* valType);
    const char* GetValType() const;
    void SetOTag(const char* oTag);
    const char* GetOTag() const;
    void SetEngUnit(const char* engUnit);
    const char* GetEngUnit() const;
    void SetDesS(const char desS[]);
    const char GetDesS() const;
    void SetByteOrder(const char* byteOrder);
    const char* GetByteOrder() const;
    void SetBytFldPos(int bytFldPos);
    int GetBytFldPos() const;
    void SetBitFldPos(int bitFldPos);
    int GetBitFldPos() const;
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, DEMData d);
    //~DEMData();
};
```

I am creating a vector to hold objects of the above type like so:

```
vector<DEMData> dems;
```

If I were to push_back 100 objects into this vector, then all 100 objects will have the exact same values as the 100th element.

Below is the code snippet:

```
DEMData demData;
  for (i = 0; attr[i]; i += 2)
  {
      if(strcmp(attr[i],"BitFldPos") == 0)
      {
      demData.SetBitFldPos(*attr[i + 1] - '0');
      }
      else if(strcmp(attr[i],"BytFldPos") == 0)
      {
        char* pEnd;
        int tmp = strtol(attr[i + 1],&pEnd,10);
        demData.SetBytFldPos(tmp);
      }
      else if(strcmp(attr[i],"ByteOrder") == 0)
      {
        demData.SetByteOrder(attr[i + 1]);
      }
      else if(strcmp(attr[i],"DesS") == 0)
      {
      demData.SetDesS(attr[i + 1]);
      }
      else if(strcmp(attr[i],"EngUnit") == 0)
      {
        demData.SetEngUnit(attr[i + 1]);
      }
      else if(strcmp(attr[i],"OTag") == 0)
      {
        demData.SetOTag(attr[i + 1]);
      }
      else if(strcmp(attr[i],"ValTyp") == 0)
      {
        demData.SetValType(attr[i + 1]);
      }
      else if(strcmp(attr[i],"idx") == 0)
      {
        char* pEnd;
        int tmp = strtol(attr[i + 1],&pEnd,10);
        demData.SetIndex(tmp);
      }
  }

  // Insert the data in the vector.
  dems.push_back(demData);
```

Why would all elements have the same values?

Comment: This is c++; is there a reason you're not using std::string in DEMData?  I'd guess that part of your problem lies in the implementation of your various SetXXXX methods in that class.

Comment: You are missing two very important members from your class -- copy ctor and op=. Also, you need to show us the part of the code where you are actually adding objects to the vector.

Comment: You are doing push_back outside of for loop. 
- only one demData will be pused to vector.
- as pointed above you are missing copy constructor and assing operator for DEMData class. Fields in DEMData class are pointer therefore You can expect weird behaviour of default generated copy constructor and assign operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

push_back() makes a copy internally, but your DEMData class has no copy constructor, so all of the elements in the vector end up pointing to the same data. When you modify one, you modify all. Since the last element is modified last, you get all of the previous elements mirroring the last one.

HTH

Comment: No, they are all copies. If you'd do something like `dems[3].byteOrder = "abc"` only that element will contain the new string. Your point would only be true if the actual strings were to be modified like `copy.byteOrder[5] = 'x'`, but those strings are `const`.

Comment: My thinking was; there's no copy constructor. So, when push_back makes a copy of the reference, it performs a shallow copy of const char pointers. So all the char pointers are still pointing to the same location. The only data that will be "properly" copied are the int bit fields. No?

Answer (score 4):

Are you doing the push_back in the loop?  If not, demData won't change.

If your push_back is within the loop, the values of demData are dependent on the attr[i] values.  If those don't change, members of demData won't change.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to call `push_back` after the end of the for-loop, so that only the last element will be stored in the vector. Is that your intention?

Also the objects might directly store the `char*` from the `attr` array, so make sure that the memory used there stays valid and is not overwritten/freed later on.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are creating a new value for the DEMData inside the loop.  If you do this :

```
DEMData dem;

for( int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++ )
{
    modifyDem( dem, i );
    vec.push_back(dem);
}
```

The vector will only contain the information of the last one modified (because the memory of the object gets overwritten every time).

If you do this :

```
for( int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++ )
{
    DEMData dem;

    modifyDem( dem, i );
    vec.push_back(dem);
}
```

You should be o.k.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you variable `attr` is being properly modified in every iteration. Your snippet doesn´t make it clear, but you are always reading the same range from `attr`. If by any chance you forgot to change this variable for each iteration, you will end up with the same elements in your vector everytime.

Answer (score 0):

This looks exactly like [push_back to a Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314196/push-back-to-a-vector) to me...is there something different this time?

Assuming that:

1. The for loop you included is
   inside another 0-99 for loop
2. attr[] is maintained somehow between
   the two for loops and contains
   either char* or std:strings

The way push_back works is it makes a copy of the data passed in. When you pass a stack object demData all of its attributes are being copied with a default copy constructor which simply copies the actual pointer which (which a simplistic version of the set functions would just pass on through). So even though you set the values into demData each pass through the loop, all you're doing is making 100 items in the vector that are all pointing at the exact same string data: The last data decoded from the source file.

If you posted the code for one of the functions like SetEngUnit that would help confirm this.

Options are:

1. Make the char* in the class
   std::string, which should manage all
   the memory for you.
2. Implement the
   copy constructor and operator= for
   your class to do a deep copy.
3. Make sure when you call the set
   methods that you pass in a distinct
   pointer each time. You'll need to
   make sure you clean it up right or
   you leak memory.